# Showing small oscillations in an animation

Tags: animation, scaling

I came across a problem where I would like to animate small (but important!) oscillations around some state. Here I attach a very very simplified example.

This is a working example of my problem:

```
μ = 1/10;
η = 1/90;

points = {{0, 5*(1 + μ Cos[t])}, {1, 3*(1 + η Sin[t])}};

Animate[
  Show[
    ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, 
      Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 6}}], 
    ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, PlotStyle -> Red]], 
  {tmax, 0, 50}, 
  AnimationRate -> 10, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

In the above both `μ` and `η` are big and the oscillations are visible. However, what if the parameters are smaller, for example:

```
μ = 1/1000000;
η = 1/900000;
```

In that case I can't see a damn thing and the animation is useless.

Any ideas on how to zoom-in to specific areas or enhance the oscillations (but not VIA manually changing the numerical value for `μ` or `η`)?

EDIT:
In reality I am working with the following function for `y` coordinate: [DROPBOX LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu554hn3s203zcq/fun.txt?dl=0) and looks something like this
[image]

Comment: Why don't you change the `PlotRange`? It seems you should take the problem the other way round: what do you want to show? `Manipulate` just did what you asked it to do.

Comment: @anderstood: `PlotRange` won't do the job. Remember that I am trying to visualize oscillations with amplitude of micro/nano-meters while the relative difference in the position of point 1 and 2 is measured on a completely different scale (meters). Take attached working case for example: The relative difference in height is 2 m, while I want to somehow visualize the oscillations with amplitude of micrometers.  I could use `PlotRange` to zoom in one point only, but that's not what I want or need.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to see something moving in a scale where it corresponds to less than a pixel. I guess it's not possible if you want to keep the scale and do not want to amplify the motion.

Comment: @anderstood Missunderstanding: enhancing the motion (the oscillation amplitudes) is exactly what I want but NOT via manually changing the numerical values of `μ` or `η` because in reality the equation for `y` coordinate is a bit more complex that the example here. In my OP I added an example of a function I am working with. So if anybody finds a way to enhance the oscillating part... - that would save my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the animation quite differently than the way you propose.

1. use a frame with custom y-coordinate ticks that magnify the y-coordinate values.
2. use `Graphics` rather than `ListPlot` and `Show`.
3. define `points` as a function.

With this approach the code is quite simple:

```
With[{μ = 1/10, η = 1/9},
  points[t_] := {{0, .5 + μ Cos[t]}, {1, .3 + η Sin[t]}}]
With[{scale = 10.^-5}, 
  yTicks = {#, # scale}& /@ Subdivide[.2, .6, 8]];

Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    {Line[points[t]], Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[points[t]]},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> {{yTicks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {.2, .6}},
    PlotRangePadding -> {.05, .025}],
  {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: demo]

I did my coding in a `Manipulate` expression rather than an `Animate` expression because I find it easier to experiment with a `Manipulate`. However, it is trivial to convert between the two kinds of expressions, so you should have no trouble doing so.

#### Update

Here is a version that lets you set the parameters `μ` and `η` with sliders. I hope it addresses the issue you raised in the comment you made below.

**Definitions**

```
pts[t_, μ_, η_] := {{0, 5 + μ Cos[t]}, {1, 3 + η Sin[t]}}
yTicks[λ_] := Table[{i, N[i 10^-λ]}, {i, 1, 7, 1}]
```

**Parameter controls**

I define a custom slider to set the parameters because the built-in one doesn't offer something I need, which is to apply a scaling factor of `10^-λ` to the values of the parameters which are displayed to the right of the sliders.

```
SetAttributes[delocalize, HoldFirst]
delocalize[symbl_Symbol] := 
  First @ StringSplit[SymbolName[Unevaluated @ symbl], "$"]

paramCntrl[var_Symbol, min_, max_, step_, λ_] :=
  Row[
    {delocalize[var], 
     " ", 
     Slider[Dynamic @ var, {min, max, step}], 
     " ", 
     Dynamic[var N[10^-λ]]}]
```

**Animation**

```
With[{λ = 6},
  DynamicModule[{μ, η},
    Panel[
      Column[
        {paramCntrl[μ, 0., 2., .1, λ],
         paramCntrl[η, 0., 2., .1, λ],
         Animate[
           Graphics[
             {Line[pts[t, μ, η]], Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts[t, μ, η]]},
             Background -> White,
             Frame -> True,
             FrameTicks -> {{yTicks[λ], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
             AspectRatio -> 1,
             PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {1, 7}},
             PlotRangePadding -> {.1, .25},
             ImagePadding -> {{50, 5}, {15, 5}}],
           {t, 0, 2 π},
           Paneled -> False,
           AnimationRate -> .5,
           AnimationRunning -> False]}],
      Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]]]]
```

[image: animation]

**Notes**

1. I have given you two orders of magnitude over which to adjust `μ` and `η`.
2. The values for `μ` and `η` shown in the above screen capture correspond to the values you gave in your question.
3. The option `AnimationRate -> 10` that you gave in your question is far too fast. I used `AnimationRate -> .5`.
4. The solution I give here is rather more general than I think you actually need, but I believe is good provide more than is needed than to fall short.
5. If I didn't use `delocalize` the labels to left of the parameter sliders
   would display as something like `μ$123` and `η$456`.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need but I can't figure out how to zoom-in again after i change the parameters `μ` and `η` to smaller values. Can you help?

Comment: @skrat. I will look into it. It might be a little while before I can make an update because I'm busy with other things at the moment. It would help me to know the range of values over which the parameters are to vary. The order of 10^-6, which I used in my example, is already very small. How much smaller do you need to go?

Comment: In my case the order of 10^-6 will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Presentation of an idea for the first animation:

```
\[Mu] = 1/10;
\[Eta] = 1/90;

points = {{0, 5 + \[Mu] Cos[t]}, {1, 3 + \[Eta] Sin[t]}};

a1 = Animate[
  Grid[{{Grid[{{ListPlot[{points /. t -> tmax, points /. t -> tmax}, 
         Joined -> {True, False}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, 
         Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Full, 
         PlotRange -> {{-0.05, .05}, {5. - 2 \[Mu], 5. + 2 \[Mu]}}, 
         Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}], 
        ListPlot[{points /. t -> tmax, points /. t -> tmax}, 
         Joined -> {True, False}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, 
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
         PlotRange -> {{0.95, 1.05}, {3. - 2 \[Mu], 3. + 2 \[Mu]}}, 
         Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, True}}, 
         FrameTicks -> {{True, All}, {All, True}}]}}]}, {Grid[{{Show[
         ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, Joined -> True, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
          PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {0, 6}}], 
         ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, PlotStyle -> Red], 
         Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, True}}, 
         FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, 
            Directive[FontOpacity -> 0]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
         ImageSize -> 350]}}]}}], {tmax, 0, 50}, AnimationRate -> 10, 
  AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

For the second case:

```
\[Mu] = 1/1000000;
\[Eta] = 1/900000;

points = {{0, 5 + \[Mu] Cos[t]}, {1, 3 + \[Eta] Sin[t]}};

ticks1 = {{-\[Mu], -Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}, {0, 0}, {\[Mu], 
    Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}};
ticks2 = {{1 - \[Mu], 1 - Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}, {1, 
    1}, {1 + \[Mu], 1 + Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}};

ticks3 = {{5. - \[Mu], 5 - Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}, {5, 
    5}, {5. + \[Mu], 5 + Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}};
ticks4 = {{3. - \[Mu], 3 - Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}, {3, 
    3}, {3. + \[Mu], 3 + Superscript[10, Log10@\[Mu]]}};

a2 = Animate[
  Grid[{{Grid[{{ListPlot[{points /. t -> tmax, points /. t -> tmax}, 
         Joined -> {True, False}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, 
         Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Full, 
         PlotRange -> {{-\[Mu], \[Mu]}, {5. - 2 \[Mu], 5. + 2 \[Mu]}},
          Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
         FrameTicks -> {{ticks3, True}, {ticks1, True}}], 
        ListPlot[{points /. t -> tmax, points /. t -> tmax}, 
         Joined -> {True, False}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, 
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
         PlotRange -> {{1 - \[Mu], 1 + \[Mu]}, {3. - 2 \[Mu], 
            3. + 2 \[Mu]}}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, True}}, 
         FrameTicks -> {{All, ticks4}, {ticks2, 
            True}}]}}]}, {Grid[{{Show[
         ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, Joined -> True, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
          PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {0, 6}}], 
         ListPlot[points /. t -> tmax, PlotStyle -> Red], 
         Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, True}}, 
         FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, 
            Directive[FontOpacity -> 0]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
         ImageSize -> 350]}}]}}], {tmax, 0, 50}, AnimationRate -> 10, 
  AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]